# How to set active tab in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I open gnome-terminal with multiple tabs from the command line, I would like to preselect (on the command line) which one of the tabs should get focus.

I tried

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t A --active --tab -t B
```

to set tab A as the active, but instead tab B becomes the active one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the script bellow , make it executable with `chmod +x scriptname`, where script name is actual script name.

Run the script with 4 parameters. For example, I run it with 
`activetab.sh TAB-1 TAB-2 TAB-3 TAB-4`. You can call tabs anything you want, TAB-1 is just example.

You will be prompted for which tab you want to focus on, type it exactly as you've typed it in the argument

**Note**: you will need to have `wmctrl` and `xdotool` installed for this script to work ! `sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool`

**The script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author : Serg Kolo
# Date: April 11,2015
# Description: Open gnome-terminal with 4 tabs, and focus on tab with particular name
#
# set -x
echo "Which window to focus ? "
read FOCUS

gnome-terminal --tab -t $1  --tab -t $2  --tab -t  $3 --tab -t $4

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    sleep 0.5
    WINID=$(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/ && /0x/ {print $5}' | cut -d'x' -f2)


    while [ $(wmctrl -l | grep $WINID | awk '{print $4}') != $FOCUS ]; do
        xdotool key Ctrl+Page_Up
    done

fi
```

**Demo**

If you can't see animation bellow, open it in different browser (chromium or google chrome) , or follow this link :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sWMb.gif

[image]

Comment: Like the answer ? Please upvote. Solved your problem ? Click the gray checkmark to accept the answer

Comment: I'm impressed!  Upvoted!  ;-)

Comment: Great! I think I got this to work after some modifications.. :)

Comment: Deleted my post and upvoted yours...  Must've missed it a few years ago...